# Bootstrap 4.0 not working with popper.js v1.12.9

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I created a new MVC project using visual studio 2015. Then I updated the bootstrap version to `v4.0`. When I update the bootstrap it installed the `popper.js v1.12.9`.

Then I added the `popper.js` path to my `BundleConfig.js` file. Finally when I run the project in Internet Explorer it gives prompts an error.
 [image]

Any solutions please ?

Comment: Do you have jQuery included?

Comment: Please post the relevant section of the `bundleConfig.js`

Comment: The current version is popper 1.14.1 Have you tried downloading it in nuget?